# Electron app white screen but buttons are functional - Windows 7

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-7, electron, electron-packager

I recently built a small Electron app for Windows, that has a title, a file input and a button. It renders perfectly fine on Windows 10, and on most Windows 7 devices the screen is blank for a second then renders fine. However, today I was trying on another Windows 7 device, and the window is completely blank.

However, the buttons and file input **are still clickable and function as intended, but are "invisible"** (cursor does change to pointer when hovering over them, this is how I could find them - other than that they are completely invisible).

The app is built using `electron-packager`, and its `BrowserWindow` uses Bootstrap from a CDN, if this is of any relevance.

All Windows 7 devices tested run 64-bit windows, including the device with the problem. I tried running both 32-bit and 64-bit executables of the program, same behavior. I also tried running a development mode executable of the program (so that I can access Chrome dev tools), but even the dev tools do not show up.

Any idea what could be the culprit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more looking around, I found out that Electron needs at least .NET Framework 4.7.1 to run. The PC in question was still at version 4.0. However, the newer versions of .NET framework need at least Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (SP1). In short, I had to:

- Update Windows to Windows 7 SP1
- Install .NET Framework 4.8
- Delete the `d3dcompiler_47.dll` file from the build directory (see issue [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7049#issuecomment-369365328))

And now the application runs fine.